# HowTo correctly select processed XML-Element inside Loop (with PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell-Code containing XML-data:

```
[xml]$Xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-A</SequenceName>
    <SequenceNumber>01</SequenceNumber>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-A</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>01</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-B</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>02</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-B</SequenceName>
    <SequenceNumber>02</SequenceNumber>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-C</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>01</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-D</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>02</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
  </Sequence>
</Sequences>
"@

Clear-Host

( $Xml.Sequences.Sequence | Sort-Object SeqenceNumber | Select-Object -First 1 ).Package | ForEach-Object {

    $xml.Sequences.SelectSingleNode( $_.PackageFolder )

}
```

As you see, I loop through the packages in Sequence-A defined in XML.
I want to add a new text-element to the already processed package like:

```
<Package>
    <PackageFolder>Package-A</PackageFolder>
    <PackageNumber>01</PackageNumber>
    <PackageProcessed>True</PackageProcessed>
</Package>
```

To do this I need to SELECT the correct node.

In a simple sandbox I used something like:

```
$xml.xxxx.SelectSingleNode("Package")
```

Ofc it is not working like this, and I am looking for a way to target/select the currently processed node inside the loop.

I don't think, that searching for the PackageFolder-name would be useful, because maybe it won't be unique.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working like this:

```
[xml]$Xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-A</SequenceName>
    <SequenceNumber>01</SequenceNumber>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-A</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>01</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-B</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>02</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-B</SequenceName>
    <SequenceNumber>02</SequenceNumber>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-C</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>01</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
    <Package>
      <PackageFolder>Package-D</PackageFolder>
      <PackageNumber>02</PackageNumber>
    </Package>
  </Sequence>
</Sequences>
"@

Clear-Host

$Packages = ( $Xml.Sequences.Sequence | Sort-Object SeqenceNumber | Select-Object -First 1 ).Package 

foreach ( $Package in $Packages ) {

    IF ( -not $Package.PackageProcessed ) { $Package.AppendChild( $Xml.CreateElement( "PackageProcessed" ) ) | Out-Null }
    $Package.PackageProcessed = "True"

}
```